# Why i keep getting error Extension methods must be defined in a non-generic static class?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I created a new method:

```
private static void FillCircle(this Graphics g, Brush brush,
                              PointF center, float radius)
        {
            g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            g.FillEllipse(brush, center.X - radius, center.Y - radius,
                                 radius + radius, radius + radius);
        }
```

But getting on the main form class name error:

```
namespace mws
{
    class DopplerRadar
```

The error is on the DopplerRadar

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   CS1106  Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class

If i change for example the FillCircle method to:

```
private void test()
{

}
```

I'm not getting any errors.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
public class DopplerRadar
```

to

```
public static class DopplerRadar
```